# how to keep on adding rows to the dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, append, rbind

I am running a loop through all the genes present in my datasets and creating a matrix.
The matrix columns is 49 and rows will depend upon rsid.
I want to create one big matrix in which all the genes information is stored.
I am trying to use rbind option in R but it gives me only the last gene value.

```
for(k in 1:3) {  ##for gene
     z <- 0
     for(i in 1:49){  #i=tissue                                                      
         y <- list.dfs[[i]]$gene %in% genes_union[k] ##y stores the gene
         x <- list.dfs[[i]][y,]$rsid ## store the snp for the gene for a particular tissue
         z <<- unique(append(z,x))}  ##get only unique SNP for that gene and remove duplicates(SNP can be shared among tissues and will create duplicate value)
     z <- z[2:length(z)]
     models_df_gene1 <- matrix(,nrow=length(z),ncol=49)
 colnames(models_df_gene1) <- col_names
 rownames(models_df_gene1) <- z
 for(t in 1:49){
     u <- which(list.dfs[[t]]$gene %in% genes_union[k])
     a <- list.dfs[[t]][u,]
     for(j in 1:length(z)){
         b <- which(z[1:length(z)] %in% a$rsid[j])
         models_df_gene1[b,t] <- a$weight[j]
         models_df_gene1 <- replace(models_df_gene1, is.na(models_df_gene1), 0)}
}
file_chr22 <- rbind(models_df_gene1)
#write.table(models_df_gene1,file=paste0(genes_union[k],".txt"),sep="\t",row.names=T,col.names=T)
}


Input data:
genes_union:
str(genes_union)
 chr [1:21650] "ENSG00000261456.5" "ENSG00000151240.16" ...
list.dfs[[1]]:
str(list.dfs[[1]])
'data.frame':   249965 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ gene      : chr  "ENSG00000261456.5" "ENSG00000261456.5" "ENSG00000261456.5" "ENSG00000261456.5" ...
 $ rsid      : chr  "rs11252127" "rs11252546" "rs11591988" "rs4495823" 
 $ varID     : chr  "chr10_52147_C_T_b38" "chr10_58487_T_C_b38" "chr10_80130_C_T_b38" "chr10_97603_G_A_b38" 
 $ ref_allele: chr  "C" "T" "C" "G" 
 $ eff_allele: chr  "T" "C" "T" "A" 
 $ weight    : num  0.0523 -0.0335 0.0143 -0.0308 0.013
```

Does anyone know how to keep adding on to the matrix when its column length is same ?

Comment: Adding rows one at a time in a loop is one of the worst things you can do for performance. If you share a little bit of sample input and show the desired output - just a few rows to demonstrate - we can probably help you find a better way. But it's quite hard to debug code that we can't run because we don't have sample input.

Comment: I added the input data. I cannot use dput since my data is really big.

Comment: `file_chr22 <- rbind(models_df_gene1)` this line is just replacing the variable `file_chr22` each time. If you are going to loop like this(bad idea), you need to pass `rbind` the current data, and the new rows.

Comment: is there any other method instead of rbind in loop to add the values?

Comment: The `str()` output is informative but not useful. Of course you can't `dput()` your whole data set, please `dput()` a small sample that illustrates the problem, for example `dput(genes_union[1:5])` for the first 5 entries of that string, and `dput(list.dfs[[1]][1:5, ])` for the first 5 rows of the first data frame. If you can't provide us with a small sample of something that we can work with it will be very very hard to help.